# make javac compiler compile faster

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, maven

I am trying to compile 5000+ java files (a lot of these Java files contains inner class). When I use this command

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

It takes around 15-16 minutes.

I am using Java 8 and Maven 3.6. Any tips to make it much faster?

Comment: Remove `clean`. This will try to avoid recompiling classes whose sources haven't changed. Switching to a more recent Java version to compile may improve compilation (slightly).

Comment: 15-16 minutes seems pretty slow, but you also told us nothing about what machine you're running this on. You can try [running a parallel build using something like `-T 1C`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3) which may or may not help, depending on where the bottleneck is.

Comment: just a wild guess but maybe you are working on mac with m1 processor and you have wrong java for that :D

Comment: Are all those classes within a single module? Also why using `install` ?? Also as already mentioned remove `clean` ... Also upgrade more recent version of Maven ... (3.6.3 is pretty old) use most recent 3.8.6 in particular if you have multi module build....Also have you really measured your build what is really cause (check via: https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-buildtime-profiler)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the experimental maven parallel mode by:

```bash
mvn clean install -DskipTests -T $(nproc)
```

Where `-T` means **thread number** and `$(nproc)` gets the number of your CPU cores (if you are on Linux).

Comment: First parallization will only help if having a multi module build. Apart from that it's **not** experimental (existing since Maven 3.0.0 12 years ago!!) ... Using `-T 1.0C` will automatically use 1 thread multiplied by the number of cores... ("Thread count, for instance 2.0C where C is core multiplied")...

Comment: I am using the **3.6.0** and into the logs it tells me that this experimental, but this is not an issue for me because it works like a charme. ;)

Comment: Where: `and into the logs it tells me that this experimental`??

Comment: Using 3.6.0 is very old... use most recent version 3.8.6 ..